# Custom JSONP error handling showing generic “Error Occurred” page to remote users only

Tags: asp.net-mvc, exception

I’m using an `ExceptionFilter` to set the response code to `500` and show a JSONP representation of the exception:

```
filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 500;
filterContext.Controller.ViewBag.callback = GetCallBack(filterContext);
filterContext.Result = new ViewResult
{
    ViewName = GetFormat(filterContext),
    ViewData = new ViewDataDictionary(new [] { new { message = "sorry!" } }),
    TempData = filterContext.Controller.TempData
};
```

This is working fine locally, displaying:

```
whatever([{ "message": "sorry!" }]);
```

when called locally.

However, when called from a remote machine, I get the IIS7 generic “Error Occurred” page. How can I get my custom content to display instead?